# Private key: Convert a valid EC key to a equivalent RSA key

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key

I have a valid private key. When I `cat` it, I see (masked for security).

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGS[xxx]6a7EXt7CT6wSgDc+
zYYSBiL6cm[xxx]aikHV47TBj4PdBW1c
wzmUrOf2s6PWS0[xxx]LPdTjOD
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I am quite sure it is valid since `openssl ec -in my-private.key -text` I see the key fine.

I was wondering, is there a way to convert a EC key into RSA please? And if yes, how to do such?

Thank you

Comment: [tag:ssl] doesn't have anything to do with it, but [tag:rsa] and [tag:private-key] do. Don't tag indiscrimately, but do use relevant tags. They help you find your audience.

Comment: They are completely different and incompatible public key schemes, so converting an EC key into RSA doesn't make any sense.